# MIPS and $31, can't understand why data is stored in register $31

Tags: mips

I don't know too much about MIPS, because we have to do it next year at university, but, this year we got to work with lex and yacc and ofcourse we need to know MIPS. I just learned something about it few hours ago, but for example if we have 'a=-2' and 'b=-a', I know that for 'a=-2' we have something like that 'addi  $1, $0, -2', and for 'b=-a' we have something like that   'move $2, $31'. I understood untill here, but I want to know something. $31 is register where 'b' will be stored? and if yes,  what is so special at that register? Why can't be stored in $30 , or $29 for example? It is because $31 is last register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register assignment is based upon the compiler's allocation scheme, subject to the mips ABI http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html

So, if you have two variables: `a` and `b`, the compiler can assign them to any register that is available for the given purpose. Register `$31` aka `$ra` is the return address register. It's not a good choice to retain a data value because `$ra` is hardwired into the `jal` instruction.

`$0` aka `$zero` is hardwired to the value of zero. Other registers can be used for any purpose, but most compilers, and most programs, adhere to the register usage conventions of the ABI.

Thus, `$1` aka `$at` is the "assembler temporary". This is used because mips only has conditional branch instructions for equality/inequality (e.g. `beq/bne`) and does not have (e.g. `blt`). So, it has an `slt` instruction that takes an output register, which is generally the `$at` register

For your sequence:

```
a = -2;
b = -a;
```

Let's assume that `a` has been assigned `$t0` and `b` has been assigned to `$t1`. The generated sequence would be:

```
    addi    $t0,$zero,-2            # a = -2
    sub     $t1,$zero,$t0           # b = -a
```

Also, for more on what can and cannot be done with `$ra`, see my answer here: [Whether $ra register callee saved or caller saved in mips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906276/whether-ra-register-callee-saved-or-caller-saved-in-mips/37910622#37910622)

Answer (score 1):

$31 register in MIPS is the return address register. It is saved by the calling function. It is available for use after saving.

But there is no checking against that. It can be used in a lw instruction just like any other general purpose register.