# MIPS assembly language, is $ra register preserved after function call?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm a student who started learning MIPS.

I have been searching through online about whether $ra(return address) is callee saved(preserved) or not. Some tables state that it's a callee saved while some other state that it's not.

I think $ra isn't a callee saved register which means it's a caller saved register.

It's because if $ra is a callee saved register, I believe there is a problem. If we call a function(sub-routine) through jal, there is no way that the callee function is able to preserved the previous $ra value since $ra would be changed to PC+4 after the jal instruction; the caller function should save $ra in the stack beforehand. So, considering this case, $ra would be a caller saved register.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, non-leaf functions need to save/restore `$ra` themselves.

Comment: @PeterCordes Besides the jal instruction, does syscall instruction always preserve the $ra register? I'd been trying to see if there is any change, but It seems that $ra is preserved after the syscall. I don't really get how it's preserved..

Comment: `syscall` doesn't use `$ra` to save a return address; it uses a different mechanism to switch to kernel mode.  It's up to the kernel whether to preserve `$ra` or not.  SPIM and MARS documentation says their system calls preserve all regs except the return value.  I assume the same is true of Linux-MIPS system calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct?

As you already found out `$ra` is a very special case:

The `jal` instruction will already write a value to `$ra` before the called function is entered. So the calling function will already "destroy" the `$ra` register.

However someone already asked a question very similar to yours:

[Whether $ra register callee saved or caller saved in mips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906276/whether-ra-register-callee-saved-or-caller-saved-in-mips)

One answer points out that the called function **is allowed** to modify the `$ra` register so the calling function **cannot assume** that `$ra` really contains the return address. The example given in that answer is:

```
move $v0,$ra
li   $ra,0
jr   $v0
```

> Besides the jal instruction, does syscall instruction always preserve the $ra register?

On a simulator (SPIM, MARS, ...) the `syscall` instruction is one single CPU instruction which does not access any registers but the ones documented.

On a real MIPS CPU the `syscall` instruction causes that what is called "software interrupt" on x86 CPUs. A software interrupt is a special form of a function call.

However unlike the `jal` instruction the `syscall` instruction does not write the return address to the `$ra` register but to a special register (named `EPC` on MIPS R4400 CPUs), which can only be accessed using special instructions.

The function which is called (the "exception handler") will of course modify registers. And if that function calls other functions it will modify the `$ra` register.

However I think that nearly all operating systems will preserve **all** registers but the ones that are explicitly modified according to the documentation (in the case of Linux `$v0`, `$v1` and `$a3` are modified by a `syscall`).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the only other answer above (by Martin Rosenau), $ra is an exception.

It is the callee's job to save important registers THAT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN IN THE FUNCTION to the stack. However, as you (OP) pointed out, that is impossible to do with $ra, making it the exception to the rule and forcing the calleR to save $ra to the stack before jumping to the function.

Why is it the calleE's job to be the housekeeper for pushing and popping everything (except $ra)? Imagine that, for whatever reason, you decide to delete the function because you no longer need it. You can simply delete everything inside the function and have nothing else to worry about (except $ra).

HOWEVER, if it were the calleR's job to save and restore values from the stack/memory, you would have extra overhead OUTSIDE the function to worry about. It would be less clear if pushing and popping were due to the deleted function or something that comes later.